# How to use fixed time effects in r?

Tags: r

I have panel dataset with 40 variables for many cities over a period of time, from 1980-2014, and I'm trying to use multiple linear regression using only three variables but also I want to have time dummies for each and every year to control for unobserved shocks over time.

Should I create a dummy for each year? but that would create too many columns.

I don't know how to create the set of time dummies just to be in one column in R (as one variable).

I searched online but couldn't find help.

Comment: Suppose the time variable was `year`.  Run your regression with `year` as a factor variable: `lm(y ~ x + as.factor(year), data=my_data)`

Comment: Thank you. I got another problem after regressing with `factor(year)` with collinearity. I'll try to solve it anyway.